# how can i remove this weird mark in html ?

Tags: html

in this piece of html,

```
    <div>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
            <img border="0" width="26" height="25" src="facebook.gif" alt="Facebook"/>
        </a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="http://twitter.com/" target="_blank">
            <img border="0" width="26" height="25" src="twitter.gif" alt="Twitter"/>
        </a>
    </div>
```

when it's displayed in the browser, there's a small mark next to the first image. Why does it appear and how can i remove it?

Here's an image to show it :

[image]

Comment: Is this affecting all browsers, or just some of them? Also, are there CSS styles being applied to the images or the surrounding elements?

Comment: Can you show more of the code? maybe create a JSFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It's not part of one of your images?

Comment: this is all that the page contains, anyway, Vishal Deep's posted the right answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try setting the `text-decoration: none` for the two links above.

The problem you are facing is that the links are underlined by default, and there might be a line-break after the image that is causing a white-space characters, and the default `text-decoration: underline;` is showing an underline under that white-space character.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the white-space between `<img ...>` and `</a>` like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
        <img border="0" width="26" height="25" src="facebook.gif" alt="Facebook"/></a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="http://twitter.com/" target="_blank">
        <img border="0" width="26" height="25" src="twitter.gif" alt="Twitter"/></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason as I too have been struggling with this for a long time (something to do with white-space). However, what I have found is that if you set the display to inline-block, this problem goes away.

`a { display: inline-block; }`

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mznMY/

Answer (score 1):

You are using an `a` anchor which contains underline symbol

Put `text-decoration: none` to your `a`.